# When trying to install gulp I get this "EhStorAuthn.exe" is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am trying to install gulp via the command line using `npm install gulp -g` command. But, I get the following error in the console.

```
npm.cmd : '"C:\Users\(UserName)\AppData\Roaming\{6DB6FE6A-BC14-72D7-B8D3-39FB02304BE7}\EhStorAuthn.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

Even though I got the error, Gulp was installed.

Then I tried to check version of my `npm` with `npm -v` command, I also get the same error but then it displays `2.15.9`

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You should not install `gulp` globally but `gulp-cli`

Comment: That made no difference. The issue is with any `npm` command

Comment: Does the `EhStorAuthn.exe` file exsist? It seems like it should not be in that path, and it could be something virus like it seems.